Не могу установить SQL Server 2022 Express. Выдает ошибку : "Системе не удается найти указанный путь"
Не могу установить SQL Server 2022 Express. Выдает ошибку : "Системе не удается найти указанный путь".
Данные в файлу Summary:
Detailed results:
Feature:                  Службы ядра СУБД
Status:                        Сбой
Reason for failure:            Возникла ошибка при установке компонента.
Next Step:                     Устраните ошибку, пользуясь следующими сведениями, удалите
компонент, а затем запустите установку еще раз.
Component name:                Экземпляры служб ядра СУБД SQL Server
Component error code:          0x80004005
Error description:             Системе не удается найти указанный путь

А в журнале что пишут, про который там написано?
